# how to set executable path of chrome driver as path of the os (i want to make executable path as generic of driver-Selenium with python)

Tags: python, selenium, generics, webdriver, executable-path

how to set executable path of chrome driver as path of the os (i want to make executable path as generic for all the system of driver-Selenium with python)

Comment: Make driver's path in your system PATH.

Answer (score 0):

create a new folder in c drive (name it whatever you want) then go to environment variables and set path to that folder and thats it :) I hope i helped you.